# Extracting Elements From a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, extract, zero

I'm trying to extract elements from the first column of the following matrix using a for loop
    [1.0000    1.0000;
    0.4401    4.0000;
    0.0000    2.0000;
    0.0000    3.0000]
But I'm getting inaccurate values for the zero ones (example: 6.2421e-010 instead of zero)
How to fix this?

Code:

```
for h=1:K 
  summation=0; 
  for i=1:F 
   x(i,1) 
   summation=summation+x(i,1); 
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: `code` for h=1:K    
        summation=0;
            for i=1:F
                x(i,1)
                summation=summation+x(i,1);
            end
        end

Comment: But please note that x is an output of another function

Comment: @AmiraAkra can u be clear where you face the problem?

Comment: @AmiraAkra What's the summation part for, are you just trying to extract or are you summing as well. Please define your question fully

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop to extract the first column. You could do this:

```
a = [1.0000 1.0000; 0.4401 4.0000; 0.0000 2.0000; 0.0000 3.0000];
b = a(:,1);
```

Giving:

```
b =

    1.0000
    0.4401
         0
         0
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read so far:

```
A = [1.0000 1.0000; 0.4401 4.0000; 0.0000 2.0000; 0.0000 3.0000];
B = A(:,1);
```

No for loops needed..

```
if vpa(x(i,1)) < 0.0000003
  summation=summation+x(i,1);
else
 summation=summation+vpa(x(i,1));
```

Comment: Ok, this just got my attention: x is a solution matrix generated by a CVX method, and when the element values are with exponential (ex:9.052969485168205e-11), they are displayed as zero 0.000.....why is it so?

Comment: you want it to still ex:9.052969485168205e-11 is it?

Comment: vpa worked well, but what if I want to set these values to zero? Not only displaying them as zeros?

Comment: if the number is 0.0000003, i need to set it to zero

Answer (score 0):

1. If your matrix numbers are integers you dont need to write all the zeros after the dot.
2. To extract a column of a matrix use `M(:,j)` where M is the matrix and j the column you want to extract.
3. If you want to sum the elements of that column, just do `sum(M(:,j))`

   ```
   M= [1 1; 0.4401 4; 0 2; 0 3]

   c1=M(:,1)

   summation = sum(c1)
   ```